# Generate liquibase sql file with only databasechangelog table

Tags: database, properties, liquibase, changelog

I want to generate a SQL file from my changelog file which only contains the databasechangelog table and inserts in it the current state of the database. In the liquibase documentation there is an article (http://www.liquibase.org/2015/07/without-a-connection.html) where is written that you can set `outputLiquibaseSql` to `data_only` but in my case it does not work. My properties file looks like this:

```
driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath: sqljdbc42.jar
url: offline:mssql?outputLiquibaseSql=data_only
changeLogFile: cl.xml
outputFile: output.sql
```

but when I use `updateSql` via command-line it generates the SQL file with all statements and not only the databasechangelog table and INSERTS. Is there any fix for this? Or ist there another way to create a SQL file only with databasechangelog table INSERTS?
I am using liquibase 3.5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me a combination of `outputLiquibaseSql=true` and `changeLogSyncSQL` worked. So the properties file looked like this:

```
driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath: sqljdbc42.jar
url: offline:mssql?outputLiquibaseSql=true
changeLogFile: cl.xml
outputFile: output.sql
```

and then I used `liquibase changeLogSyncSQL` via command-line. Then liquibase generated a SQL file with only databasechangelog table statements.